# A contradictory result from a corollary with the fact that the quotient space of a Hausdorff space is not necessary Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

It is known that a quotient space of a Hausdorff space is not necessarily Hausdorff; however, in the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 140, it is given that

[image]

But, we can always choose $Z = X$ and $g=i$ so that $g = i$ is a surjective continuous map. Hence, if $Z=X$ is Hausdorff, then by part $b$, $X^*$ must be Hausdorff, which is not true, as there are lots of counterexamples, by what is wrong with the above argument ?

Comment: In that case, $X^*$ is homemorphic to $X$ so it is Hausdorff

Comment: And by the existence of $f$, the topology in $X^*$ is finer than the initial topology with respecto to $f$, which is Hausdorff if $Z$ is Hausdorff. And we get $(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z=X$ and $g=id$ then 
$$X^*=\{ g^{-1}(z) | z \in Z \}=X$$

I think that you are confusing $X^*$ with some quotient of $X$, which is not the case in this corollary.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed $X^*$ was some quotient space of $X$; didn't pay attention to the definition of $X^*$ there. Thanks for the answer.